# How to increase the Java Memory in Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, java, environment-variables, virtual-memory, heapspace

I am trying to follow [This Link](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/wikihow/index.php/How_to_Increase_Java_Memory_in_Windows) to increase the memory that is available to the Java Runtime Environment, because I encountered the "insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue" when running Tableau Server. But my question is: I don't even have the "Java" section as shown in the image below at all.
[image]

On this Windows Server 2012R2, I do find that the "Java Mission Control" installed on the machine but I don't know how to change the Java memory size inside it.

Can anyone give me some suggestions/advice? Thanks!

Comment: You have the 64 bit version of java installed right?

Comment: I am not sure (embarrased face)... When I ran the "java -version" command, I got 3 lines of errors: 1. couldn't open registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 2. couldn't find java.dll, and 3. couldn't find Java SE Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding it through the Environment Properties menu which can be found at:

1. From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
2. Click Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
3. In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
4. Click New to add a new variable name and value.
5. For variable name enter JAVA_OPTS for variable value enter one of these -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xmx2048m -Xmx4096m (whichever suits you)
6. Click ok and close the System Properties Tab.
7. Restart any java applications.

JAVA_OPTS is a system variable that stores various settings/configurations for your local Java Virtual Machine. By having JAVA_OPTS set as a system variable all applications running on top of the JVM will take their settings from this parameter.